# AMP-html toggleVisibility and show actions gives "Target element does not support provided action" errors

Tags: html, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I found few scraps of info about the ability to show/hide/toggle element visibility via tap event in Accelerated Mobile Pages. It is mentioned in [the docs](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-actions-and-events.md#globally-defined-events-and-actions) as a global show/hide/toggleVisibility actions. There is also an example [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/standard-actions.amp.html) how to use it.

The thing is it does not work in current state - at least for me. Brief test of the example above (see: https://plnkr.co/edit/CspuKe1I5LHTdHBWB3Cn?p=preview) gives me a bunch of `Action Error: Target element does not support provided action in [tap:normal-element.show] on [[object HTMLDivElement]]` errors.

Am I missing something? How can I use global `show`/`hide`/`toggleVisibility` actions on elements like `<div id="my-element">Hi</div>`?

Comment: If you think this is an issue you can [file here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new) which is specifically caters to AMP.

Comment: I am not sure what it is yet - my experience with AMP is very limited and I cannot rule out my own error yet. That's why I am posting here - it would be nice at least to get confirmation from more experienced users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted an issue about this on GitHub where someone kindly replied to my question: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/8035

**TL;DR** is that at the time of writing the update with those features is coming out in a week or so.